# PHP Parse content from url

Tags: php, html, dom

i need some help regarding this study script im building which im trying to fetch articles from a website.

Currently im able to get the article from 1 element but failing to get all elements, this is an example of the url im trying to fetch

```
<div class="entry-content">
</div>

<div class="entry-content">
</div>

<div class="entry-content">
</div>
```

This is my PHP code to get the content of the first div :

```
function getArticle($url){

    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $first_step = explode( '<div class="entry-content">' , $content );
    $separate_news = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );
    $article = $separate_news[0];

    echo $article;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really use PHPs [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class for parsing HTML. In terms of your example code, the problem is that you're not processing all the results from your `$first_step` array. You could try something like this:

```
$first_steps = explode( '<div class="entry-content">' , $content );
foreach ($first_steps as $first_step) {
    if (strpos($first_step, '</div>') === false) continue;
    $separate_news = explode("</div>" , $first_step );
    $article = $separate_news[0];
    echo $article;
}
```

Here's a small [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/rKVOY)

Comment: Amazing work you did here ! I can clearly see it now, it ended up in being stuck with first result .  Regarding the DOMDocument ive tried before using vanilla coding but seems like they do not support classes but only ids and element tags

Answer (score 1):

I have used this library before http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ . Full documentation is found here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm .
It's very easy to use and does a lot more. 
You could select your articles like:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
$articles = $html->find(".entry-content");
foreach($articles as $article) echo $article->plaintext;
```

Comment: It does not work with latest lib your code: [07-Dec-2018 16:10:07 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function file_get_html() in /home/gmtemhic/public_html/index.php on line 19

Comment: It should work. Looks like the library is not included on your page. Download it here https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simple_html_dom.php/download and include `simple_html_dom.php` on your page.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Although it is a bit tricky to select nodes by CSS class, you can do it with [`DomXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) like this:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($url);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="entry-content";
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " entry-content ")]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent . "\n";
}
```

The advantage is now also that HTML entities and other HTML that might occur inside the article content is converted as expected. Like `&amp;` becomes `&`, and `<b>bold</b>` just becomes `bold`.